# C++ adding class to namespace to create new class object

Tags: c++, c++11, interface, smart-pointers

I created a smart pointer project for self study similar to https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15351/Implementing-a-simple-smart-pointer-in-c i did not want to use `std::shared_ptr`  and i did not want to use `weak_ptr` or `unique_ptr`

Mini version of project
http://cpp.sh/957bl

Now i want to expand the project and create a `interface` that makes objects and a copy function.
The original project contains a copy constructor and a regular constructor.

**What i would like to know is how to create the copy function and the make function.**

Errors im getting:

```
Error   C3861   'makeShared': identifier not found  main.cpp    22  
Error   C3861   'copyShared': identifier not found  main.cpp    12  
Error   C2653   'TestAllocator': is not a class or namespace name   PointerInterface.hpp    35
```

Comment: And where are those functions declared or defined? Apparently not in any of the header files you include (and you show us neither of them).

Comment: On a different note, *why* don't you want to use the standard smart pointers? Is it only for learning purposes, or is there some other underlying problem that you want to solve? If it's some underlying problem, then perhaps you should ask about *that* instead of attempting to reinvent (pretty poorly I would argue) the wheel.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude OP wrote "for self study"

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude sorry i had to rush off to the hospital. I have updated the question with my old project that is working and with the correct interface.hpp that i am trying to create and need help with

Comment: `makeShared` and `copyShared` are defined in `Interface.hpp`, which doesn't appear to be included anywhere. `TestAllocator` is not declared anywhere in the code you've shown.

Comment: It would be better if you could minimize your example. Start by removing everything that is not needed, even function bodies if they are not used. Then put everything into a single file that reproduces the error and post this.

Comment: On a side note, using a `#define` for a constant is quite unusual for C++. Just use a `static constexpr int MAXREFCOUNT = 3`.

Comment: @Jens yes i was testing out new things, in the pastebin i posted there is the older version there i just have a private int in my recounter class

Comment: @IgorTandetnik what do you mean the #includes are there or maybe this could be what i have forgotten ?

Comment: @Jessica The pastebin code is not minimal. It `#includes` other files and contains a lot of code that does not matter. What you should aim at is a complete minimal example (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Prefereably, this should be a single file which reproduces exactly the error message. No other problems or code should be in the example. The code posted contains at least one other error in `makeShared`. You return a pointer to `SharedPointer` because you `new` the return value.

Comment: @Jens the pastebin was just a previous file that worked that i am now expanding, it was not minimized version. I removed most of the sharedpointer.hpp functions and left only the constructor deconstructor.

I do not know how to add the functions in the interface correctly and i dont know how to add the interface correctly to the project

Comment: @Jessica You could start with a minimal working example in a single file, e.g. http://cpp.sh/4gx3a. From there, extract code into their own header files step by step.

Comment: @Jens i followed your instructions thanks i did not know about the shell. I added now the mini to the project that only contains the make and constructors

Comment: The error message you cite mentions `interface.hpp`. But in the code you show (after numerous edits), no such file is present. Which means that the code you show is not the same code you actually compile and have difficulty with. Also, `restrictedRefCounter` is not declared anywhere.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik these are the 3 files i have main.cpp, pointerinterface.hpp and sharedpointer.hpp.

That interface.hpp is pointerinterface.hpp

Comment: @Jessica You should edit your post with the concrete code you are compiling, the command line and file/directory structure. And give detailed information, e.g. by copy-pasting the commands instead of describing them.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you want to do when vexed by not seeing why declarations are missing is to look at the preprocessor output for the file being compiled. It should be on a menu in most C++ IDEs or available via a command line flag. The output is often excessively long, but it will unambiguously show you the input going to the compiler.